# How to change the default page in the Language Switcher?

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, mod-languages

I am creating a multi-language page in Joomla with 5 different languages.

Everything is ok except for the language switcher.

My home page is set for English, when I try to change the language from the index page, the others language redirect me to the last menu item of each language and not to the home page of each one.

I don´t know what I have to do in order to redirect to each default home page when I clic the flags. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set the default homepage for each language?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a documentation available to setup multi-language joomla site and in that document you will get idea to set home page menu item for each language.
You can see the "Defining a Default Home page Menu item per language" section.

Here is the documentation URL:
https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Language_Switcher_Tutorial

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to JSE! Please provide more details. Your answer is similar to link-only answers.